# Custom color item-row css depending group id, vue, html

Tags: php, html, css, sql, vue.js

I need custom color .row-item by id_parent. sometime .a some time .b I'm using vue

```
<template>
   <div class="row-item" v-for="row in list" > {{row.name}}   {{row.id_parent}} </div>
<template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
           return{
            list:[
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 1 }, 
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 1 }, 
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 3 }, 
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 3 }, 
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 4 }, 
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 4 }, 
                 ]
             }
        }
</script>
<style>
.a{
    border-left: 2px solid #9c27b0;
}
.b{
    border-left: 2px solid #5c6bc0;
}
</style>
```

I would like this result: first id_parent class .a and the next .b , next .a ...

```
        <div class="row-item a"> lorem 1 </div>
        <div class="row-item a"> lorem 1 </div>
        <div class="row-item b"> lorem 3 </div>
        <div class="row-item b"> lorem 3 </div>
        <div class="row-item a"> lorem 4 </div>
        <div class="row-item a"> lorem 4 </div>
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
<template>
   <div :class="'row-item '+getRowClass(row)" v-for="row in list" > {{row.name}}    {{row.id_parent}} </div> //Changes added
<template>

<script>
    export default {
        data(){
           return{
            list:[
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 1, class: 'a' }, //Changes added
                        {name:"loem", id_parent: 1, class: 'b'  }, //Changes added
                 ]
             },
        },
     computed: {
      getRowClass() {
       return item => {
          if(item.id_parent === 1) return 'a';
          return 'b';
       }
      }
     }
 }
</script>
<style>
.a{
    border-left: 2px solid #9c27b0;
}
.b{
    border-left: 2px solid #5c6bc0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i would like by group ex: `id_parent : 1 ` all id_parent 1 class a, and the next group id_parent: 2 class .b the parent_id it will be increment in groups. this is came from axio

Comment: Please check my updated answer...I have added the computed property to achieve it

Comment: if you see the parent_id it will be increment, what will happen next when the `parent_id` is 3 , 4 , 5, 6? i need the next .a next .b by group `parent_id`. 1=a, 2=b: 3:a , 4:b by group rows parent_id

Comment: Then you might define the mapper object for each of the IDs or better get it in the response